# Tastypie obj_create - how to use newly created object?

Tags: django, tastypie

When a new item is created using Tastypie, I want to be able to add it to a user's attribute which is a many-to-many field.
RIght now my obj_create looks like this:

```
  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    return super(GoalResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, user=request.user)
```

I want to create the new object, but when I want to be able to add it to the request.user's attribute goal_list. But, what I have will immediately create the object in the database. How would I create the object and then add it to the user's goal_list attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't show us your resource definition, but assuming you are using `tastypie.resources.ModelResource` as your base class, this should work:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle = super(GoalResource, self).obj_create(
        bundle, request, user=request.user)

    user = request.user
    user.goals.add( bundle.obj )
    user.save()
    return bundle
```

This is because the `obj_create` method of `ModelResource` class returns a bundle which contains the saved object (`bundle.obj`) and you can manipulate this object in your `obj_create` method as shown and only then return it.

I have also assumed that request.user contains a valid `User` object (i.e. authenticated), you need to make sure it does for above to work or you should add some error handling code for the case when it does not.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet so I figured I would put a second answer.  The answer above is correct I just wanted to add that request no longer exists in the obj_create call.  You can access the current request via bundle.request:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#accessing-the-current-request

Thanks for the answer above, it helped me as well!

Comment: Answers everywhere need to be updated because of this :)