# Convert POST to PUT with Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Full Disclosure: Cross posted to Tastypie Google Group

I have a situation where I have limited control over what is being sent to my api. Essentially there are two webservices that I need to be able to accept POST data from. Both use plain POST actions with urlencoded data (basic form submission essentially).

Thinking about it in "curl" terms it's like:

```
curl --data "id=1&foo=2" http://path/to/api
```

My problem is that I can't update records using POST. So I need to adjust the model resource (I believe) such that if an ID is specified, the POST acts as a PUT instead of a POST.

## api.py

```
class urlencodeSerializer(Serializer):
    formats = ['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist', 'urlencoded']
    content_types = {
        'json': 'application/json',
        'jsonp': 'text/javascript',
        'xml': 'application/xml',
        'yaml': 'text/yaml',
        'html': 'text/html',
        'plist': 'application/x-plist',
        'urlencoded': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    # cheating
    def to_urlencoded(self,content): 
        pass
    # this comes from an old patch on github, it was never implemented
    def from_urlencoded(self, data,options=None):
        """ handles basic formencoded url posts """
        qs = dict((k, v if len(v)>1 else v[0] )
            for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(data).iteritems())
        return qs


class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all() # "id" = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        resource_name = 'foo'
        authorization = Authorization() # only temporary, I know.
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
```

## urls.py

```
foo_resource = FooResource

...
url(r'^api/',include(foo_resource.urls)),
)
```

In #tastypie on Freenode, Ghost[], suggested that I overwrite post_list() by creating a function in the model resource like so, however, I have not been successful in using this as yet.

```
def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get('id'): 
        return self.put_detail(request,**kwargs) 
    else: 
        return super(YourResource, self).post_list(request,**kwargs)
```

Unfortunately this method isn't working for me. I'm hoping the larger community could provide some guidance or a solution for this problem.

Note: I cannot overwrite the headers that come from the client (as per: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#using-put-delete-patch-in-unsupported-places)

Comment: I use the method obj_create like this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070173/tastypie-obj-create-how-to-use-newly-created-object

and works fine

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on user creation where I wasn't able to check if the record already existed. I ended up creating a custom validation method which validated if the user didn't exist in which case post would work fine. If the user did exist I updated the record from the validation method. The api still returns a 400 response but the record is updated. It feels a bit hacky but...

Answer (score 1):

```
from tastypie.validation import Validation

class MyValidation(Validation):

    def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
        errors = {}
        #if this dict is empty validation passes. 

        my_foo = foo.objects.filter(id=1)
        if not len(my_foo) == 0: #if object exists      
            foo[0].foo = 'bar'    #so existing object updated
            errors['status'] = 'object updated'  #this will be returned in the api response

        return errors 

    #so errors is empty if object does not exist and validation passes. Otherwise object
    #updated and response notifies you of this

class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all() # "id" = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        validation = MyValidation()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Cathal's recommendation I was able to utilize a validation function to update the records I needed. While this does not return a valid code... it works.

```
from tastypie.validation import Validation
import string # wrapping in int() doesn't work

class Validator(Validation): 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        pass

    def is_valid(self,bundle,request=None):
        if string.atoi(bundle.data['id']) in Foo.objects.values_list('id',flat=True):
                # ... update code here
        else:
            return {}
```

Make sure you specify the `validation = Validator()` in the `ModelResource` meta.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't return a valid code. Did you able to find solution for it?

Comment: It returns failure but does not actually fail. That was my solution.