# Tastypie overriding obj_create

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the following resource and I am attempting to override obj_create. If I don't override it, things work perfectly, but when I override it it gives a POST error. Any leads? Would really appreciate an answer though I believe tastypie is really not getting any answers on stack overflow these days.. which is pretty annoying. I am thinking of possibly switching my stack for the same reasons..

The code is as follows:

```
class OrderResource(BackBoneCompatibleResource):
  person = fields.ToOneField(PersonResource, 'person', full=True)
  restaurant = fields.ToOneField(RestaurantResource, 'restaurant', full=True)
  itemList = fields.ToManyField(OrderItemResource, 'itemList', full=True)

  class Meta:
    object_class = Order
    queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by("-time_updated")
    resource_name = 'order'
    allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','delete','patch']
    authorization = Authorization()
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist'])
    authentication = ClientAuthentication()
    authorization = OrderAuthorization()
    always_return_data = True
    filtering = {
        "restaurant" : ["exact"],
        "time_created" : ["gte"],
        "person" : ["exact"]
    }

  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    print "Entered Order Create"
    return super(OrderResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
```

And the order model is :

```
class Order(models.Model):
  restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
  tableNumber = models.CharField(max_length=2)
  PLACED = 'p'
  ACCEPTED = 'a'
  READY = 'r'
  ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (PLACED, 'Placed'),
    (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
    (READY, 'Ready'),
  ) 
  order_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES, default=PLACED)
  itemList = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, null=True)
  tax = models.FloatField()
  tip = models.FloatField()
  cost = models.FloatField()
  time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  time_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

As I said, if I remove the obj_create() function from the resource, post happens properly. I am unable to understand what wrong I am doing by just writing the default function as specified in the docs? I might be missing something very obvious. Thanks for your time..

The specific error I get is the following, not sure if it helps much though..

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('obj_create() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)',), <traceback object at 0x10d30fb90>
```

Comment: What is the error? Post the complete traceback.

Comment: I get the following error, I don't know how specific or helpful that is..
`(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('obj_create() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)',), <traceback object at 0x10e33f368>)`

Comment: Anybody? I have been really struggling with this, and seems like a petty issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return super(OrderResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
```

To this:

```
return super(OrderResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request=request, **kwargs)
```

`request` [must be passed as a keyword argument](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#obj-create).

Answer (score 2):

When you call `super().obj_create`, you are passing the parent method an argument it doesn't expect. The error message tells you what's wrong and it makes sense when you look at the parent method here in the [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#obj-create). It catches `**kwargs`, but see how there's no `*args`? That means it can't handle the `request` parameter that you pass it.

```
Resource.obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs)  # Tastypie
```

I recommend you define `obj_create` on your subclass using the **same method signature** so you don't confuse the expectations of the caller. The parent doesn't explicitly handle `request` so you shouldn't either. Final code then:

```
class OrderResource(BackBoneCompatibleResource):
    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        print "Entered Order Create"
        return super(OrderResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Jcotton. That was pretty helpful. Somehow all earlier sources I found for obj_create(), they specified 3 arguments, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070173/tastypie-obj-create-how-to-use-newly-created-object
But, thanks, I understand this much better now!!

Comment: Looks like the request param went away in [v0.9.12](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/compare/v0.9.11...v0.9.12/#diff-6764d072338c962ca11757d6456e71cbL1182). Don't forget to upvote helpful answers =)

Comment: Thanks @JCotton. Yes I upvoted it. I was earlier trying to checkmark both, because both were helpful, but unfortunately stack overflow allows only 1 checkmark! BTW on a side note, can you help me with this question ? .. I often face a hard time getting responses on Tastypie questions on stack overflow, also development efforts on Tastypie have been a little slow for some time.. would you personally recommend me switching to Django-rest-framework, or using Flask/Bottle, or any other more reliable recommendation, or tastypie is good enough ?

Comment: Good question. Django Rest Framework certainly has a lot of steam. If I was starting a new project, I'd use it. For two sizable past projects, I've used Tastypie without problems. I like Tastypie but it has slowed and isn't at a 1.0, which it really should be by now. If you have a lot invested in Tastypie I don't see any need to switch as long as it's meeting your needs. If starting something new or needing other features, DRF is the top choice to consider.

Comment: Thanks JCotton. I really value that advice. Yes, I have invested quite a lot on Tastypie by now! But will stay open to moving (to DRF) as soon as I can find more resources!