# Django Tastypie create API with complex calculation on database fields

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am new to **Djnago/Tastypie** and having trouble in creating an API with **complex calculation**. The model is as following :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
'''Customer details.'''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=10,
                                  max_digits=15, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=10,
                                   max_digits=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now the task is to create an API which will have ***latitude, longitude, radius*** as request parameters and we have to calculate all the Customers whose latitude and longitude falls within the given radius to the requested point.

Till now I have only experience of creating simple API using Tastypie. Can anybody please suggest me the possible resource class for this or any  **Django/Tastypie tutorial** that might be helpful for creating this API  ? 
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070173/tastypie-obj-create-how-to-use-newly-created-object

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches both in a standard ModelResource

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):

  class Meta:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    ...
```

Do all the work of creating the object and add it to the bundle you return:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):


    ref = bundle.data['ref']
    value = complex calculation here

    bundle.obj = MyModel.objects.create(ref=ref, value = value)


    return  bundle
```

Use the parent class to create the object and put it in the bundle and then amend the value:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):


    bundle = super(MyResource, self).obj_create(
        bundle, request, user=request.user
    )
    bundle.obj.value = complex calculation here
    bundle.obj.save()


    return  bundle
```

Comment: But this API does not suppose to create new data, instead it will be only a GET API which will return all nearby lat,long (existing in the database) to the requesting lat,long.

Comment: Not if you call as POST

Comment: wouldn't this  create new MyResource data in database, I need to only fetch the details from database and not create .